# If objects are key value pairs, how can functions be objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, theory

If all functions in JS are objects, and objects are just collections of key:value pairs - how do complex functions become objects? Say a function thats taking a param number, doing complex calculations on it and returning the result - how is *that* an object? How do you store it as key/value pairs?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept here. All functions are objects, but it doesn't mean that function body is converted into the key-value pairs.

Comment: functions _do_ hold own key/value pairs, and inherit some from Function.prototype: name, length, call(), etc. I often "publish" properties to the surrounding function object, for caching, sharing among many other functions w/o global pollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects *are* collections of key-value pairs indeed, but they are ***not just*** so.

Think of this ability as an interface: given a JavaScript object, you are guaranteed to be able to access its members (or elements) via a syntax of `obj.foo` or a `obj['foo']`. But at the same time, they can also have other abilities. Functions, in this case, is an example that can be called by a `fn()` syntax.

In fact, TypeScript allows you to declare a type that can do more than just key-value pairs:

```js
type Type = {
    'foo': RegExp;  // a directly guaranteed member
    [number]: string;  // a rule-based convention:
                       // you can always get a string by a numeric index
                       // (or undefined)
    Method(): number;  // member function
    get children: HTMLElement[];  // getter/setter
    { new(): SomeClass };  // constructor of certain type
};
```